# In Python, How to limit opening a window or pushing a button with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, module

I was doing a project with Tkinter and I ran into a problem. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
Root = Tk()
def Open():
    Root1 = Toplevel()

MyButton = Button(Root, text="Open A New Window!", command=Open).pack()
mainloop()
```

The problem with this code is that it will open 10 windows if I push the button 10 times. I tried this to solve it:

```
from tkinter import *
Root= Tk()

def Open():
    Root1 = Toplevel()
    MyButton = Button(Root, text="Open A New Window!", command = Open, state=DISABLED).grid(row=0, column=0)

MyButton = Button(Root, text="Open A New Window!", command = Open).grid(row= 0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

But this also doesn't work because after I close the New Window I can't open it again after that because the button will stay disabled.

Comment: Have you tried simply checking if the window exists before opening it?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below should work. Not the best solution but will allow you to re-enable the button when the second window is closed.

```
from tkinter import *
Root= Tk()

def Open():
    Root1 = Toplevel()
    Root1.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda x=Root1: on_closing(x))
    MyButton['state'] = DISABLED

def on_closing(window):
    MyButton['state'] = ACTIVE
    window.destroy()

MyButton = Button(Root, text="Open A New Window!", command = Open)
MyButton.grid(row= 0, column=0)

mainloop()
```